# Run Background action in MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timer, scheduled-tasks

Buenos dias.

I need to perform following task , and unfortunately have no idea from what to start with.

We have an MVC 4 application , we need to perform some automatic clean up action each 15 minutes. How can this be achieved in MVC application.

Is there any "Scheduled Tasks" avaliable for MVC application ?

Gracias.

Comment: sounds like you need a Windows Service to do clean-ups here, not an ASP.NET MVC application. This would involve having a timer running every 15 minutes to do your cleanup.

Comment: @Network Solutions .. Do you mean reach out from client every 15 minutes or Just run a task on the Server(s) on a scheduled time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options there, all lised with code examples here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries such as `Quartz.net`, `HangFire`, `FluentScheduler`
but `Quartz.Net` is very famous,
You can find a tutorial about that in this link [Quartz.net Tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net)